# Notification Channel creation and deletion

Tags: android, android-notifications

Created a notification channel with some set on setting and id "X" and then on user action deleted the same notification channel but when I created the new notification channel with same id(X) and name but changed the setting it is not effecting. Notification channel is created but the settings are same as previous.

Functionality is to change the notification ringtone/sound within app.

Tried creating the notification channel with different id (timestamp) and keeping rest same then notification sound does not appear.

Question here is how we can change the notification sound within app and if as per documentation we cannot modify the notification channel setting how some apps able to do that?

Comment: Correct - you cannot modify a notification channel; I believe some apps do something similar to you, but use a new name for each new channel. This is not recommended as it is better to let the user set their own values if they want to.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier WhatsApp does the same but no new channel appear under notification category. I wonder how they do it. If anyone can explain I will be obliged